# Kakfa - change topology properties in run time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am currently having a set of topologies running, I want to change the topology attributes in runtime like

1. changing the thread count
2. Adding source topics to existing list of topics
3. Adding sink

Is it possible to change the properties in run time without stopping the kafka stream. One idea which I had was to stop the kafka stream, then load these configurations and start again. But doesn't seems to be an ideal solution to this. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Changing the thread count of an instance is easily possible. You just need to `close()` the `KafkaStreams` client, change the configuration, create a new client and restart it. Most people would do this with a complete restart of the corresponding JVM.

Adding source topics and sink topics is not easily possible. Especially for source topics, you need to stop all instances, and afterward restart them one by one including the new source topics. The reason is, that the used partition assignor assumes that all instances subscribe to the exact same topics. If this assumption is violated, i.e., if some instances subscribes to a new topic, those partitions of the new topic might be assigned to an "old" instance that was not updated yet, and this would lead to a crash as the "old" instance does not know how to handle an assigned partition it did not subscribe to.